# Why is SwitchCompat not working on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Why is SwitchCompat not working and have this gray rectangle shape? I think I've tried almost everything but it's still don't want to work.

Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ustawienia">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

<include layout="@layout/content_ustawienia" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_animacja"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
    
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You have to use **androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat**. Don't mix androidx and support together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
```

use

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
```

Besides this you are mixing `support library` with `AndroidX library`. Try to remove `support library` as they are deprecated.

If you didn't migrate your project to `AndroidX` cleanly Then migrate it by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from `Android Studio` menu bar and press **Do Refactor**.

Check [official documents](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) for further details.

Comment: @willie244, Please hit the upvote so that other can find it helpful

Comment: Ok. It worked! Do you know how to make this "on click" gray color white or transparent ?  https://i.imgur.com/gV24o9c.png

Comment: Hi @willie244, This is separate question. Please ask it in separate thread to keep it clean. Hope you understand. We are here to help you. Thanks